# Fraction class troubleshooting for Fraction Driver

Tags: java, oop, driver

I am in my first semester with programming with Java and we just started getting into OOP and I ran into a small problem with my code (no surprise). Need some help from the masters that you are to figure out what is missing, I know I'm pretty close to the answer. Basically I am given a fraction driver for the fraction class and I need to write the class myself. Everything in the driver has to stay the way it is.

Here is the driver:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FractionDemo
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
Fraction c, d, x;       // Fraction objects

System.out.println("Enter numerator; then denominator.");
c = new Fraction(stdIn.nextInt(), stdIn.nextInt());
c.print();

System.out.println("Enter numerator; then denominator.");
d = new Fraction(stdIn.nextInt(), stdIn.nextInt());
d.print();

x = new Fraction();     // create a fraction for number 0


System.out.println("Sum:");
x.add(c).add(d);
x.print();

x.printAsDouble();

x = new Fraction(1, 1); // create a fraction for number 1

System.out.println("Product:");
x.multiply(c).multiply(d);
x.print();

x.printAsDouble();

System.out.println("Enter numerator; then denominator.");
x = new Fraction(stdIn.nextInt(), stdIn.nextInt());
x.printAsDouble();

}
} // end main
```

Here is the Fraction class that I have.

```
public class Fraction
{
private int numerator;  // numerator of the fraction
private int denominator;   // denominator of the fraction

//**************************************************

public void Fraction()
{
numerator = 0;
denominator = 1;
}
// default constructor

public void Fraction(int n, int d)
{
numerator = n;
denominator = d;
}
//two parameter constructor

public void print()
{
System.out.println(numerator + "/" + denominator);
} //print fraction as n/d

public void printAsDouble()
{
System.out.printf("%f", numerator/denominator);
} //print fraction as double

public Fraction add(Fraction other)
{
//add
// calling object = calling obj + parameter
int n = this.numerator * other.denominator +
this.denominator * other.numerator;
int d = this.denominator * other.denominator;
this.numerator = n;
this.denominator = d;
return this;
}  
//multiply
public Fraction multiply(Fraction other)
{
int n = this.numerator * other.numerator;
int d = this.denominator * other.denominator;
this.numerator = n;
this.denominator = d;
return this;
}

} // end Fraction class
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
FractionDemo.java:19: error: constructor Fraction in class Fraction cannot be applied to given types;
    c = new Fraction(stdIn.nextInt(), stdIn.nextInt());
        ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

FractionDemo.java:23: error: constructor Fraction in class Fraction cannot be applied to given types;
    d = new Fraction(stdIn.nextInt(), stdIn.nextInt());
        ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
FractionDemo.java:35: error: constructor Fraction in class Fraction cannot be applied to given types;
    x = new Fraction(1, 1); // create a fraction for number 1
        ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

FractionDemo.java:44: error: constructor Fraction in class Fraction cannot be applied to given types;
    x = new Fraction(stdIn.nextInt(), stdIn.nextInt());
        ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
4 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared your constructors like this:

```
public void Fraction()
public void Fraction(int n, int d)
```

Constructors do not have return types. Declare them:

```
public Fraction()
public Fraction(int n, int d)
```

Comment: Damn, that was it. But now I am stuck at printAsDouble, 
I need it to be printed as a double.

Here is sample session.

Enter numerator; then denominator.
5
8
5/8
Enter numerator; then denominator.
4
10
4/10
Sum:
82/80
1.025
Product:
20/80
0.25

I tweaked printAsDouble to this 
public void printAsDouble()
{

  double fractionDouble = (double) (numerator / denominator);
  System.out.println(fractionDouble); 
}
I am getting 1.0 and 0.0 instead in sum and product.

Comment: I fixed that too! had to change this 
double fractionDouble = (double) (numerator / denominator)

to this

double fractionDouble = (double)(numerator)/(double)(denominator)

Comment: Correct.  When you divide two integral types you get truncation like that. As you discovered, you have to coerce at least one of the dividend or divisor to a floating point type to get a correct floating point answer.